# using sharethis with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, facebook, sharethis

I am trying to use sharethis in my angularjs app as it is used by rest of the website(not written in angularjs ) as well  . The usual script is included in the html ::

```
 <script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
 stLight.options({
  publisher:'xxx'
});
```

I am using http , as i am testing it in localhost . I have created a facebook like wall in my angularjs app .. and i want to implement sharing for each of the images displayed in my wall . Since sharethis takes information from the meta tags,url, etc and creates the api for sharing  automatically i guess , i have none of this to give to sharethis as of now . i tried using tags like st_url, st_title etc as given in this [article](http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/475079-share-properties-and-sharing-custom-information) , but i was not successful .

In rest of the website, this span tag is used (ex: facebook) , for sharing , but all the images have their own url in this case

```
<span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'><i style="color: #3a5795;" class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></span>
```

What approach should i take for using sharethis in my scenario, or i have no other option other then using  [angular-socialshare](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-socialshare).

Your ideas would be very helful .
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Do hell with the rest of the website , I used angular-socialshare for this instead of sharethis . But i am not deleting this question , in case somebody stumbles upon this situation